# export all InDesign book to text

Tags: text, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to export all documents in a book to plain txt format.
I've tried the "ExportAllStories" scripts already in InDesign and of course it only picks up the current document. I've also downloaded a text exporter from Rorohiko Workflow Resources and that only picks up one document. 
Does anyone know any other programmes or plugins i could use for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an AppleScript that will process all documents in a book:

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS6"
    set theFiles to file path of book contents of book 1
    repeat with aFile in theFiles
        set theDocument to open aFile
        --export content script code here
    end repeat
end tell
```